# I'm dazzled with strange syntax issue with MySQL calculated column

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, calculated-columns

I have a calculated column for concatenating fields into an adress. It worked but I altered the table and added some columns and now I get an error. I do not know where I went wrong.

I use: Serverversion: 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

When I add the following SQL script via PHPMYadmin it accepts the syntax. Everything seems ok. When I add a row via my application I get an error. When I remove the calculation, it's again ok and can add a row.

```
ALTER TABLE app_fd_halo_objects
MODIFY c_adres varchar(255) GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
(IF(c_box_volgnr > '', (CONCAT(c_straat, ' ', c_huisnummer, ', boxnr ', 
 c_box_volgnr, ', ',c_plaats)), (CONCAT(c_straat, ' ', c_huisnummer,  ', ', c_plaats))))
stored;
```

When I add the script again, all seems ok, no error message. But when I go to change that column and without changing something press the save button. PHPMyadmin comes with:

[image]

I hope someone can help.

I'm sorry it's in Dutch, but I think its understandable

Comment: We need more details. It seems to work fine here - https://dbfiddle.uk/gQjIEez0

Comment: Could be PHPmyadmin that's unhappy

Comment: Seems, your string contain symbol ``\``  not masked by \ or you use ``o\'r`` instead like ``'o''r'``

Comment: This is in the field: if((`c_box_volgnr` > _utf8mb4\'\'),concat(`c_straat`,_utf8mb4\' \',`c_huisnummer`,_utf8mb4\', boxnr \',`c_box_volgnr`,_utf8mb4\', \',`c_plaats`),concat(`c_straat`,_utf8mb4\' \',`c_huisnummer`,_utf8mb4\', \',`c_plaats`))

Comment: Show values for ``c_box_volgnr``, ``c_straat``, ``c_huisnummer``, ``c_plaats``, ``c_huisnummer``

Comment: c_plaats  longtext utf8mb4_unicode_ci 
c_straat  longtext utf8mb4_unicode_ci 
c_huisnummer longtext utf8mb4_unicode_ci 
c_box_volgnr varchar(255) utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: I don understand what is `` _utf8mb4\'\'``

Comment: That shows in PHPMyadmin in the column settings after running the SQL-script.

Comment: Use double brackets. `.. AS (( {expression} )) ..`.

Comment: This sounds like a phpMyAdmin bug involving the nested quotes in the column definition.